# Как обработать такой массив на php

Tags: php

в качестве value в цикле

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$message .= $key; 
  $message .= ": " . $value . "\n"; 
}
```

приходит вот такой массив:

```
{"sys":"none","systranid":"0","orderid":"1987774240","products":[{"name":"Шарики для роликов","quantity":"2","amount":"2000","price":"1000","sku":"00-00003462"},{"name":"Коньки","quantity":"3","amount":"6000","price":"2000","sku":"00-00003463"}],"amount":"8000"}
```

Как мне его обработать и собрать в другой массив, чтобы можно было с ним работать вот так:
(из массива выше мне нужно только name и quantity.)

```
foreach($produts as $el) {
echo $el[name].' / '. $el[quantity].'шт'; 
}
```

цикл должен вывести:

```
Шарики для роликов / 2шт
Коньки / 3шт
```

Это вообще массив или json ответ, чтобы примеры найти на php?

Comment: От куда взялся `$produts` и куда делся `$message`?

Comment: $message это общее сообщение. сам массив лежит в $value

Answer (score 0):

```
$postData = json_decode($_POST);

if($postData === false)
{
   return \Exception('Json невалидный!');
} 

if(!isset($postData['products']))
{
   return \Exception('Нет ключа products!');
}

foreach($postData['products'] as $product)
{
   if(isset($product['name']) && isset($product['quantity']))
      echo $product['name'].' / '. $el['quantity']. 'шт'; 
}
```

Comment: не работает. на строчке foreach($postData['products'] as $product)
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. в примере ниже верно разбор json идёт

Comment: в json_decode вторым параметром передать true

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST='{"sys":"none","systranid":"0","orderid":"1987774240","products":[{"name":"Шарики для роликов","quantity":"2","amount":"2000","price":"1000","sku":"00-00003462"},{"name":"Коньки","quantity":"3","amount":"6000","price":"2000","sku":"00-00003463"}],"amount":"8000"}';

$json=json_decode($_POST,true)['products'];
$out=array_map( function($v){ return $v['name'].' / '.$v['quantity'].'шт'; }, $json);

echo implode('<br>',$out);
```

Comment: работает. благодарю